# Почему не  выполняется оператор if?

Tags: .htaccess, php

В htaccess имеем такое:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ([^/]*).html f2.php?id=$1
```

В самом файле:

```
<?session_start();
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($_GET['id']=1) {header ("Location: http://localhost/w10/dom.html");};
if ($_GET['id']=2) {header ("Location: http://localhost/w10/raduga.html");};
if ($_GET['id']=3) {header ("Location: http://localhost/w10/radius.html");};
?>
```

Короче, делаю ЧПУ!
Есть такой код. Почему оператор if неправильно выполняется? Все время берется только последний if, даже если и условие не выполняется...

Comment: @qwerty17, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Deonis, это опять я) каким оператором вместо id=3 вставить слово arka и каким оператором вывести изменненный url в адресной строке? можно кусок кода - буду очень признателен? как практически грузить из строки адресной одно - а показывать посетителю другое?

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!!! Буду очень ждать!!!

Comment: Могу тут выложить ссылку на архив или давайте мыло.

Comment: Буду рад если выложите здесь ссылку. Спасибо большое)))

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, Deonis! Сейчас посмотрю)))) Спасибоооо!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас уже второй вопрос на эту тему. Намучаетесь вы. Моё личное мнение, которое могут и оспорить, но лучше делать глобальный рерайт:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

В этом случае, все запрося приходят на index.php, в самом начале файла у меня подключен файл обработчик, который разбирает URL и выполняет то или иное действие/запрос и т.д. Просто одна ошибка в htaccess - приводит к тому, что сайт ложиться, а PHP настолько гибкий, что обработать эту задачу не составит труда. Отловить очень просто:

```
$request =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

В $request у вас будет что-то типа такого **/domashnij_tekstil/matrasy_matroluxe/** (у себя взял), теперь разбираете URL с помощью explode(), например.

```
$request =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_parts = explode('/',$request); // массив всех частей URL
```

Дальше, делаете с этим то, что нужно. К примеру, у вас был переход на страницу контактов. Вы получаете URL /page/contacts/

```
$url_parts[0] // пустой (можно отсеять раньше)
$url_parts[1] // page
$url_parts[2] // contacts
```

Проверяю первую часть, определяю, что работаем со страницами, вторая часть показывает с какой именно - контакты

Comment: Спасибо, что поняли меня Deonis))) ну я понимаю, что это нужно прописать в htaccess... а можете примерную схему этого файла-обработчика привести.. спасибо... )))

Comment: СПАСИбО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!! делаю так:
include_once('nav.php');

if ($url_parts[2]='f2.php?id=6') {header ("Location: http://localhost/site/arka.html");};
то у меня отображается нужный адрес - но страница не та показывается.. почему? или вы не такую реализацию имели в виду?

Comment: Не нужно больше никуда переадресовывать! Для начала, надо бы определиться. У вас, к примеру, страницы достаются из базы? И ссылка у вас уже должна быть как ЧПУ, а вы, как я вижу, их строите по обычному принципу. Не http://site.ru/f2.php?id=6 , а сразу http://localhost/site/arka.html

У меня ощущение, что вы не совсем понимаете смысл и принцип ЧПУ. Может быть поэтому у вас и возникают проблемы.

Comment: Не понял вас как это реализовать? все равно ЧПУ должен отображаться в адресной строке. Да, у меня все страницы достаются из базы. Например таблица объектов: арка, ее id, описание и т.д. Для каждого объекта завести в базе определенную ячейку с ЧПУ... я вас правильно понял или нет?

Comment: Правильно... В обычном случае, у вас ссылка выглядела так:

    <a href="http://localhost/site/f2.php?id=6">ARKA</a>

Где id - это индекс страницы ARKA в базе. При ЧПУ можно эту же ссылку написать красиво:

    <a href="http://localhost/site/arka/">ARKA</a>

Именно так в адресной строке она и выглядит. Но id в этом случае мы же не получаем. Поэтому, вместо id мы используем часть url "arka"

Comment: Нет, этого файла arka.html реально не существует. Я ЧПУ понимаю так - если реальное отображение адреса не удобно для посетителя, то можно его переписать в удобном варианте. Вместо http://site.ru/f2.php?id=6 показывать  http://localhost/site/arka.html. И даже если  arka.html не существует, то посетитель все равно если введет в строке http://localhost/site/arka.html. то попадет на страницу http://site.ru/f2.php?id=6.

Comment: Ну, так всё верно. Из http://localhost/site/arka.html выдираете последнюю часть "arka" и по ней вытягиваете соответствующее из базы на эту же страницу "index.php", в то время, как для пользователя в адресной строке остается висеть http://localhost/site/arka.html

Answer (score 6):

Потому что у вас все условия выполняются, т.к. присвоение переменной $_GET['id'] происходит успешно :). Нужно писать

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 1) ....
```

Comment: я понимаю... просто все время берется и выполняется последняя сторчка из этих всех if-ов.... т.е. не обязательно условие выполняется или нет - оно выполняется....

Comment: @qwerty17, еще раз внимательно перечитайте ответ и обратите внимание на количество знаков "равно".

Comment: спасибо! увидел!

Comment: та ладно! =)

Comment: Вам покажется это удивительным, но так оно и есть!

Comment: поставил два раза "равно" и все равно пропускаются все условия и выполняется только последнее.. каким бы оно ни было(((

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно зачем вы инициализируете id а дальше все равно сравниваете с $_GET . 
Попробуйте вот так :

```
<?session_start();
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
switch($id){
  case 1 :
    ...
    break;
  case 2 :
    ...
    break;
  case 3 :
    ...
    break;
}
```